# Magento 1.9 : How do I update all downloadable products for old orders?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a product with downloadable PDFs. I recently updated the PDF with a new version. The problem is that customers who bought the old version continue download the old PDF.

How can I get all old customer orders to download the updated PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I place the following code into a .php script in the Magento root. You can call it via the CRON or your web browser.

```
<?php

    require('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    $select = getDb()->select()
        ->from(getTable('downloadable/link'), array('link_id', 'link_file', 'product_id'));

    if (($links = getDb()->fetchAll($select)) !== false) {
        foreach($links as $link) {
            $linkId = $link['link_id'];
            $productId = $link['product_id'];
            $file = $link['link_file'];

            $select = getDb()->select()
                ->from(getTable('downloadable/link_title'), 'title')
                ->where('link_id=?', $linkId)
                ->limit(1);

            $title = getDb()->fetchOne($select);

            echo sprintf("Updating %s to %s<br />", $file, $title);

            $cond = getDb()->quoteInto('product_id=?', $productId);

            getDb()->update(getTable('downloadable/link_purchased_item'), array('link_id' =>$linkId,'link_title'=>$title,'link_file'=>$file), $cond);
        }
    }

    function getDb($conn = 'core_read') {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($conn);
    }

    function getTable($table) {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($table);
    }
```